# Framework7 how to init an autocomplete component upon a popup

Tags: html-framework-7

I have a text field (input type="text") served in a popup in F7.
I want that input will fire the autocomplete component.
But this component served in the background and only can be seen when user closes the popup.

I know it is something about z-indexs but I have not found the proper fix for it so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Initiate the autocomplete component with: `openIn: 'popup'`
instead of `openIn: 'page'`